# Oracle: Call SP with IN AND Out parameter

Tags: oracle, delphi

First of all my knowledge of Oracle is very limited.

I have inherited a large Delphi project using Oracle, it have been upgraded to Oracle 11g. And now I have some problems calling Stored procedures with both `IN`  and `OUT`: parameters

Lets start with the SP's (It is placed in a package )

```
PROCEDURE GetAccessObjects(AAccessObjects OUT CURSOR_TYPE);
```

and the definition of `CURSOR_TYPE`

```
TYPE  CURSOR_TYPE IS REF CURSOR;
```

Then the Delphi Code:

```
procedure TDBApi.GetAccessObjects(var ResultSet: TADOStoredProc);
var
  SP: TDbStoredProc;
begin
  SP := CreateStoredProc(SQLPackage + 'GetAccessObjects');
  try
    SP.MaxRecords := mrAll;
    SP.Open;
    ResultSet := SP;
  except
    SP.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

When executing the Delphi code it works just fine!

Then I've created a GetAccessObjects2, and added an `IN` parameter to the interface:

```
PROCEDURE GetAccessObjects2(ALotteryID IN INT, AAccessObjects OUT CURSOR_TYPE);
```

`ALotteryID` isn't used for anything inside the SP, it's just a dummy paramerer!

Then I call it from Delphi:

```
procedure TDBApi.GetAccessObjects2(var ResultSet: TADOStoredProc);
var
  SP: TDbStoredProc;
begin
  SP := CreateStoredProc(SQLPackage + 'GetAccessObjects2');

  try
    ParamAdd(SP.Parameters, 'ALOTTERYID', 1, ftInteger, pdInput, -1);

    SP.MaxRecords := mrAll;
    SP.Open;
    ResultSet := SP;
  except
    SP.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

And I get an error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETACCESSOBJECTS2'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The Delphi code have been running for approx 10 years so it must be some diffrence in the database! Either due to upgrade or due to.

So in short: Help needed calling GetAccessObjects2 from the given Delphi code.

Comment: ALotteryID is still a parameter and you still need to supply it even if it is ignored within the procedure.

Comment: I do supply ALotteryID  but I do not supply AAccessObjects

Comment: Of course! my mistake.

Comment: With your last question you said that you were going to talk to Oracle about using SP as a function. What was their reply?

Comment: Oooh I totally got forgot about that. I'll ask tomorrow.

Comment: I have to say, looking at the Oracle website, you seem to be abusing stored procedures. To avoid inconsistences and ambiguities, and just from the point of view of clarity, if I wanted to use a stored function I would define it as a FUNCTION (which Oracle supports) rather than a PROCEDURE with an *out* parameter. Under the hood they might be equivalent today, but that does not mean they will be tomorrow...

Comment: @Dsm can you show me an example

Comment: You might need to include the parameter to the cursor too since you're now providing the ALotterID parameter.  If you're already declaring the cursor in the CreateStoredProc method (we can't see your code!!) you'll need to remove it and declare it after your ALotteryId parameter.  Or change the declaration of your procedure so your cursor is first and ALotteryID is after

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have Oracle installed and is many years since I used it, so I am unable to test. What I suggest is that you look at the web tutorial for stored procedures and functions, and imagine how you would solve the problem yourself, rather than just accepting someone else's code. Try it on a simple test procedure/function yourself. That way you will learn how to deal with Oracle, and be in a better position to maintain this code.